# kendo ui upload, restrict only 1 document

Tags: kendo-ui

Would you be able to advise how you could only allow 1 document to upload in kendo ui upload. If the file have been selected, then we unable to upload the new one. Please find the code below. Thank you

```
<div class="configuration k-widget k-header">
    <span class="infoHead">Information</span>
    <p>
        The Upload can be used as a drop-in replacement
        for file input elements.
    </p>
    <p>
        This "synchronous" mode does not require
        special handling on the server.
    </p>
</div>
<form method="post" action='@Url.Action("Submit")' style="width:45%">
    <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
        )
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See Kendo.MVC.UI.Fluent Doc's for **Multiple(System.Boolean)**](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/UploadBuilder#multiplesystemboolean)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .Multiple(false)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using javascript/html5 version:

```
$("#selctor").kendoUpload({ "multiple": false });
```